# Explode() function error in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have stored the values to the database by seperating it with comma , now i want to separate each values here . I tried this using implode function but it shows only the first value. please help.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Facilities</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="1" 
                      <?php
                                                                                        if ( isset($selectdata))
                                                                                        {
                                                                                        foreach($selectdata as $r )
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            $i = explode(',',$r->facilities);
                      echo set_value('facilities[]',$i) == 1 ? "checked" : "";
                      }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                  ?>

                      ><label for="checkbox5" >Guide</label></div>

                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="2"><label for="checkbox1">Site Seeing</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="3"><label for="checkbox2">Hotel</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="4"><label for="checkbox3">Travel</label></div>
                      <div class="col-sm-6 checkbox"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="facilities[]" value="5"><label for="checkbox4">Food</label></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace below code

```html
 $i = explode(',',$r->facilities);
```

with

```html
 $i = explode(',',$r->facilities]);
```

Comment: here i am able to get the first value

Answer (score 0):

can you please replace

```
 $i = explode(',',$r->facilities]);
```

to

```
 $i = explode(',',$r->facilities);
```

because It has an extra bracket(]).

Answer (score 0):

`implode` is used to group an array back to a single string. `explode` is used to separate a string to an array.

```
$string =  'hello how are you,are you ok';
$explode =  explode(',', $string);
print_r($explode); 

//Result: Array ( [0] => hello how are you [1] => are you ok )
```